# Corrupted file from Google drive API

Tags: rest, curl, post, google-api, google-drive-api

I wish to use google drive api as a backup solution. So, I have a zipped folder that is uploaded with curl to a service account using *updloadType=resumable*.

The zipped (tar) file is a ~30mb folder and seems to upload to drive api without errors.

My issue is that I cant unzip the file (seems corrupted) after downloading it from my service account. when I try to untar I have :

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format.                   
tar: Child returned status 1.              
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.
```

It already worked back in september. The file that i've already been able to download and extract back then aren't working anymore.

I know the downloaded file come the same size as the original file. (not empty)
and I specify *X-Upload-Content-Type : application/x-gtar* in my header.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uploading other files and downloading them to check if it will still persist? Or try downloading the file using web

Comment: Yeah. I've tried to upload other different files in the same format ( tar.gz ) and downloading them. Same problem. back in september i tested a few upload/download and it was going fine.

Comment: @RustyShackleford have you tried using another extension or archive format?